# Terraform module secret

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I'll trying to create my first module terraform based on a provider who need an api_key.

```
provider "foo" {
 api_key = secretapikey
}
```

I don't wan't to expose this secret (and configuration) in projects that will use this module.

This is my current implementation, but all projects must re-declare these variables and set the associated environment variables

```
# module file /module/foo
provider "foo" {
 api_key = var.api_key
}

variable "api_key" {
  sensitive = true
}
```

In the project that will use the module I have to define the variable again (+ export)

```
# project in other repository that use the module
# export TF_VAR_api_key="secretapikey"
variable "api_key" {
  sensitive = true
}

module "bar" {
  source = "../module/foo"
  name   = "toto"
  
  api_key= var.api_key
}
```

How can I improve this ?

Comment: "How can I improve this?" Improve what exactly?

Comment: In all the projects (using the module) I don't wan't to re-declare the api key and I don't want users of this module to have this key.  Actualy I made progress using environment variable (available for this provider) with Gitlab CI variables.

Comment: If you can do this entirely with in-process environment variables retrieved dynamically in a pipeline and remove it entirely from your TF config, then yes that would be an improvement by security.